# How to estimate the norm of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

There is a matrix as following,
\begin{eqnarray}
A = \left (
\begin{array}{l}
 0 \quad  \quad \quad \quad  \quad \quad \quad ~~ 1\\
 b   \quad ~~~0 \quad  \quad \quad \quad \quad a\\
 ab \quad ~~ b \quad  ~~~0\quad \quad ~a^2\\
\vdots \quad \quad~~~ \ddots ~~\ddots \quad  \vdots\\
a^{n-2}b  \quad \cdots ab \quad b \quad a^{n-1}
\end{array}
 \right ),
\end{eqnarray}
where $A \in \mathbf{R^n}$, $a,b \in \mathbf{R},$and $0 <a < 1$, $|b|<1$. Then how to estimate the norm or the eigenvalue of $A$ and $A^k$, where $k \in \mathbf{N^{+}}$.

Comment: I presume the matrix elements above the diagonal are all zero, except on the last column, right?

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify which norm, let me take the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm), $||A||_F^2=\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}^2$, which gives
$$||A||_F^2=\frac{\left(b^2-1\right) a^{2 n}+a^{2 n+2}-a^2 \left(b^2 n+1\right)+b^2 (n-1)+1}{\left(a^2-1\right)^2}.$$
For large $n$ and $|a|,|b|<1$ this tends to $||A||_F^2\rightarrow  n\frac{b^2}{1-a^2}$.